# Generating TestNG reports

Tags: testng

I am running Test cases in testNG. By default it is producing results in a folder called "test-output" and overriding that folder every time it runs. I want to create seperate report folder every time it runs and place my results. How to do tat.??

Comment: Do you use some build automation tool as Apache Maven or Apache Ant?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the output directory, the exact answer will vary depending on which build tool you use (e.g. command line: "-d", ant: "outputdir", etc...).

Look up the documentation of your build tool for the details.

Comment: Thanks u.I have configured it. But Now i want create my own HTML reports for my project like our default HTML report. I tried to use the methods like getPassedTests() and the overridden methods in ITestresult and TestListener. But none of the method is getting any thing.

Comment: The documentation clearly explains how you can create your own reports, look up "IReporter".

Answer (score 0):

Well, i would just suggest a simple copy of the html reports that are contained in the test-output directory.  Here is what I do:

```
1. Log output of my tests to "test-output/work/version/timestamp"
2. Email the emailable-report.html  using a Java SMTP mailer class
3.  Copy the 600KB of html report files into my "test-output
    /work/version/timestamp"  to archive the reports.  This isn't always
     necessary IMHO.
```