# Multiple folders to reports in TestNG Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, testing, report, testng, exploratory

I'm running Test Cases with TestNG Eclipse plugin. How can I specify a distinct folder as output to the HTML reports by configurating testng.xml? 
I've seen Cedric's answer to this very similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5401746/generating-testng-reports/), but I couldn't obtain the same on TestNG Eclipse plugin. I've tried ,  and another bunch of similar things I've seen in the doc and nothing worked.

Extending the question a bit, we want to be able to run tests repeatedly and pick at any time the last n (say 20) reports, is it possible? It happens sometimes we use TestNG to do a lot of exploratory test. As some fails are rare and hard to repeat (and in the first approach they may not be predicted as such), sometimes the "explorer" just re-run the test and lose that inconstant fail.

Thanks in advance to any answer to the primary or a bit extended question, Regards, Henrique

Answer (score 0):

try by passing argument -doutputdir in arguments tab